# Am I eating too much fat? How healthy fat help to lose weight?

Tags: food, fat, hiit

I am now following a healthy eating cookbook by a body coach. 
I am doing an HIIT training routine he has suggested for 20 minutes, 4 times a week.
The confusion I have is the amount of fat I am consuming following his cookbook.
His logic is to have carbohydrates only after the HIIT session and food with healthy fats the rest of the time. 
He suggests eating healthy fat helps to lose weight? How is this possible? Can someone explain this to me please? 
Having a full avocado with bacon for breakfast, is that healthy with the amount of workout I do?

Comment: Can you define healthy? Are you defining that as a healthy body or healthy weight loss? Please be aware that eating fats will not inherently make you fat.

Comment: one of his recipe includes filo pastry,cream. I thought these to be unhealthy food items. so was bit worried that I might be following something unhealthy. but thanks your comment. It does make sense

Comment: I would ask him to explain his "cookbook" with some solid facts based on research.

Comment: Fat storage is regulated by insulin. The more insulin, the more fat storage. 50% of Insulin is produced in response to diet. Carbs cause a lot of insulin secretion; protein causes a little bit, and fat causes none.

Answer (score 2):

To lose weight: Calories In < Calories Out

Eating Fat does not make you fat. Eating too much makes you fat.

The specific fat/carb/protein breakdown of those calories influences your energy levels and rate of muscle growth (amongst many other things) but **does not directly affect your weight loss**. Again, to lose weight: Calories In must be less then Calories Out.

You eat more satiating (filling) foods by cutting carbs in favour of fats. You get more food and feel more full eating that way. Cutting carbs and increasing fat to counteract the calorie change is a fine way to lose weight provided you remember, Calories In < Calories Out.

Comment: -1 because of the calories in calories out nonsense. calories out (and hunger) are regulated by hormones. If you eat the same # calories butter and sugar, your insulin release will be totally different, and so will your calories out, independent of your exercise routine.